# I want to track internal URL that brought the URL to the next page or exit page

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager, utm-tracking

I want to track the URL of the current page, then pass it to a URL variable to the next page.

```
For example 
https://www.mywebsite.com
https://www.mywebsite.com/about/?fromsource=https://www.mywebsite.com
https://www.mywebsite.com/about/careers/?fromsource=https://www.mywebsite.com/about
https://www.mywebsite.com/contact/?fromsource=https://www.mywebsite.com/about/careers
```

So everytime someone moves to the next page, the URL of the previous page is add to a URL variable in the next page.

Comment: I am also using https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/transfer-utm-parameters-google-tag-manager/ to transfer UTM parameters from one page to another and then another set up to pass those UTM parameters through a form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right way. I would use Google Analytics API referral data. But you can create the following shortcode:

```
function get_current_page_link () {
    global $wp; //get global wp query
    return home_url( $wp->request ); //get the url of the current page
}
add_shortcode('get_current_page_link ', 'get_current_page_link ');
```

If you want to add the code via PHP code:

```
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/about/?fromsource=<?php echo do_shortcode("[get_current_page_link]"); ?>">About</a>
```

If you want to use it in your editor you can add url's as such:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/about/?fromsource=[get_current_page_link]
```

The editor in the text mode, it will show up like this:

```
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/about/?fromsource=[get_current_page_link]">About</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to write. I want it to be dynamic. So no matter where I am on the site, it should add a variable to the url parameters and its value should be the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use document.referrer?
So e.g. create a new variable in your web-analytics system and use the following js code to populate it:

```
function includeReferrer() {
  var ref = document.referrer,
      loc = document.location.href,
      newLoc;
  if (loc.includes('?') != -1) {
    newLoc = loc + "&fromsource=" + ref;
  } else {
    newLoc = loc + "?fromsource=" + ref; 
  }
}
```

In this case, you are not overwriting the actual URL, but instead create a new string which includes the requested parameter and can be used for any kind of tracking purpose.

Comment: If you want to do so only for internal referrers, you can add another if-clause to check "ref" for your domain.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. So I think this would work, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Another thing I was trying to do is use the default "Referrer" variable in Google Tag Manager, but for some weird reason, no matter what it only returns the root domain url in the value. When I test it in the debug mode.

Comment: Haven't worked with the default variable so for, but it sounds like it is build to strip the referrer-URL of all parameters, hashs and so on. 
You can add a new javascript var (node: a custom js var is not neccessary) for document.referrer, if you are planning to use it more than once.

Comment: Another addition to my original JS-Code:
.includes() is not supported in IE. You can use .indexOf() in case you want to be safe.